# What's missing for a successfully deploy of my node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile

I've spent a lot of time to do exactly the sames as in manuals of heroku for node.js deployments. I'm using nedb as datastore and node.js 14.x. Is one of them the issue? No further plans what it could be.

heroku log

```
2020-11-09T07:11:42.803302+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2020-11-09T07:11:42.803322+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2020-11-09T07:11:42.803323+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2020-11-09T07:11:42.812099+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at http://localhost:49728/
2020-11-09T07:12:40.832978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-11-09T07:12:40.849869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-11-09T07:12:40.929805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-11-09T07:12:40.964808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Procfile

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
  },
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "hbs": "^2.9.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "nedb-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "nedb-promises-ts": "0.0.1-4",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/nedb": "^1.8.11",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.13.0"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import express from "express";

import { indexRoutes } from "./routes/indexRoutes.js";
...
const app = express();
...

app.use("/", indexRoutes);
...
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Seems like the app crashes due to the port that it tries to bind. Re-deploy the app and try again.

Comment: Have you tried to use "0.0.0.0" or "127.0.0.1" as "hostname" ?!

Comment: @Harshana Serasinghe heroku restart --app ... done -> still the same problem with same error message

Comment: @Marc I guess in the past, I've tried with 127.0.0.1, but I'm not sure. But no matter you are my hero, it works with 0.0.0.0!